# Convert windows form to a picture

Tags: .net, winforms, drawing

I looked around and I may have confused google with the keywords.

I am looking to implement a support module in my windows forms application where when a user clicks on a button, an email is sent to the support team, with an attachment of a screenshot (form in question)

I am looking for something like

form.SaveAsImage(path)

any thoughts on how this can be implemented or have I missed the obvious

.net 3.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the [Control.DrawToBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) method and make sure the form has focus when you run the code.

```
using (Graphics gfx = form.CreateGraphics())
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height, gfx))
    {
        form.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, form.Width, form.Height));
        bmp.Save(fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Focus isn't relevant, my form dumped correctly even when app was behind visual studio :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for letting me know. I read somewhere someone had problems when there was no focus, but that might've been in an older version.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the Graphics object (gfx). Is this line necessary here?

Comment: It is not strictly necessary, but it should have been used as the final parameter to the Bitmap's constructor. That ensures the bitmap that is created matches the resolution and attributes of the screen. The sample code also should have been using using. I fixed both of those problems; this is a very popular topic for unknown reasons.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a Howto on this: ["HowTo: Print a Windows Form"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6he9hz8c.aspx)

However, I really think that you should implement printing in your application.  Perhaps this will help(?): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188767.aspx

Comment: This is usefull to me for another question, but not for this. I am trying to get a screenshot and I think the PrintDocument is more for reporting - i havent tested this, it may serve the purpose.