# Converting a windows chart form to a picture

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, drawing

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981094/convert-windows-form-to-a-picture) similar question, which I tried to implement, but it didn't work.

I have a class that creates a chart and has a second constructor if someone wants to save the chart as an image. However, the images that are being saved are just of the form background, not the chart. Here is my code.

```
public ChartForm(String path)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SaveGraphAsImage(path);
    }

private void SaveChartAsImage(String path)
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
        this.bmp.Save(path + this.Name, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

Comment: If you're using the out of the box chart control, that supports saving as an image. If you're NOT using that, how are you drawing your chart?

Comment: No repro on the .NET Chart control.  It isn't clear what control you are using.  Not supporting DrawToBitmap() is otherwise not unusual, it is often overlooked.  Contact the vendor or author for support.

Comment: If the chart is a control, try using `chart1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, chart1.Width, chart1.Height));` instead of `this`

Comment: I tried using the SaveImage, and it worked better, but it only saves the chart legend. After I draw my chart, I do this:  `this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(684, 462);
            this.Controls.Add(this.chart1);
            this.Name = "GraphForm";
            this.Text = "Form1";`

Comment: Again, what control(s) are you using to draw your chart? Without that knowledge, we cannot answer your question.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by saving the image of the chart after the chart was populated with data.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `DrawToBitmap()` method (which gives some problems (*Exceptions*) on big controls), because the `Chart` class has the [`SaveImage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd456175.aspx) method.

```
//using System.Drawing.Imaging;
myChartControl.SaveImage(path + this.Name, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: How to provide  path for the image here? Plz help