# How to save an image from a picturebox to jpg

Tags: vb.net, system.drawing, savefiledialog

I have been able to save a file as a .jpeg, but the image won't load, has anyone got a suggestion?

```
    Private Sub Btnconfirm_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btnconfirm.Click

        MsgBox("A receipt will now be saved to your files", vbOKOnly, "Thank you for your purchase")

        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        MsgBox("Thank you for choosing Tiny Theatre, have a nice day.", vbOKOnly, "Thank you")
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles SaveFileDialog1.FileOk
        Dim FileToSaveAs As String = SaveFileDialog1.FileName

        Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FileToSaveAs)
        objwriter.Write(PictureBox1)
        objwriter.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: After the image saves, it appears wherever I save it (like it should), but the image won't open, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What type of control is `PictureBox1`?  Have you looked at the content of the generated file in a hex editor?  Does the image open if you change the extension to something else, such as `.png`, `.gif`, `.bmp`, etc?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: If you're not sure about hex editors, fine.  Have you tried opening the file in Notepad?  Most of the file will probably look like garbage, but somewhere among the first few characters ought to be `JFIF`.

Comment: Can I also say you're being very vague with some of your comments?  *the image won't open* - how have you tried to open it, and what happened?  What error messages (if any) did you see?  *it won't save the file full stop* - what do you mean by this?  Code appears to run OK but file doesn't appear in Windows Explorer?  An error message was reported attempting to save the file?  By being vague and leaving out the details you are making it very difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but I managed to figure it out :)

Comment: Glad to hear you figured out the problem.  Would it be possible to detail how you solved your problem?  That way, if somebody else has the same problem as you and comes across this question, they'll then know how to solve their problem.

Comment: Well, basically I add a second picturbox made visibility false, then used this code in SaveFileDialog:

        Dim img As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.ClientSize.Width + 2,        PictureBox1.ClientSize.Height + 2)
        Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
        Dim p As Point = PictureBox1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
        p.Offset(-1, -1)
        gr.CopyFromScreen(p, New Point(0, 0), PictureBox1.Size)
        PictureBox2.image = img
        PictureBox2.Image.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)

Answer (score 9):

Didn't try it, but might this do it?

```
Private Sub SaveFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles SaveFileDialog1.FileOk
    Dim FileToSaveAs As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp, SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(FileToSaveAs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
End Sub
```

If you need to set encoder parameters (like jpeg compression) you will need an overload of the Save method. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx

The provided code saves the picturebox control in a serialized form to a file that has an extension jpeg. Renaming a text.txt file to text.jpg doesn't make it a valid jpg image. This is the same.

Comment: I gave it a try and it won't save the file full stop.

Comment: What type of control is PictureBox1? Is it a PictureBox control?

Comment: It might be because FileToSaveAs only contains a filename and not a full path. I edited the code so that the file is saved in the temp directory.

Comment: I must note, this is basically making a screenshot of some textboxes and comboboxes with a picturebox

Comment: Can you show the code how the screenshot is made? You can edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: The code I put in the question is the code for a screenshot which saves, it's just that the image itself won't work when I try to open it.

Comment: I think you might need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981094/convert-windows-form-to-a-picture

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'
:(

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is in the PictureBox control and the Image property of that PictureBox control.
Think of a TextBox control. To store the text a TextBox contains you don't save TextBox, you save TextBox.Text. Likewise, to save the image a PictureBox container, you don't save the PictureBox, you save the PictureBox.Image property.